# Java 8 How to concat query condition based on a list of string

Tags: java-8, concatenation

How can I write the following code in a more elegant way using java8?

```
String query = "select device, manufacturer, type from devices where username = ?";

boolean found = false;
if (deviceTypes.stream().filter(t -> "typeA".equals(t)).findFirst().isPresent()) {
    query += " AND type like 'A%'";
    found = true;
}

if (deviceTypes.stream().filter(t -> "typeB".equals(t)).findFirst().isPresent()) {
    if (found) {
        query += " OR ";

    } else {
        query += " AND ";
    }
    query += " type like 'B%'";
}
```

If in the device types there are both A and B, the query should contain both with OR.

Example:-

```
deviceTypes="A,B" --> query condition => AND type like 'A%' OR type like 'B%';
```

Example:-

```
deviceTypes="B" --> query condition => AND type like 'B%';
thanks a lot
```

Comment: If your query is for a specific database, like _MySQL_, for example, then please [edit] your question and add the tag for the database you are using. You may be able to write a [SQL] query whose text does not need to be modified dynamically.

Comment: what is the type of `deviceTypes` and why doesn't just `deviceTypes.contains("typeB")` work here? That seems like an awfully complex way of writing that.

Comment: `filter(predicate).findFirst().isPresent()` is an unnecessarily verbose variant of `anyMatch(predicate)`, but as Joachim Sauer said, if the predicate is just an `equals` test and the source a `Collection`, there is no need for a Stream operation at all, as just `contains` will already do, which is not only much simpler but also more efficient, e.g. when the source is a `Set`.

Comment: thanks guys.. First implementation used  `contains` since deviceTypes is a List<String>.. I would understand if I can remove the boolean and the if condition around the OR /AND for building a query like `select device, manufacturer, type from devices where username = ? and (type like 'A%' OR type like 'B%')` in case both string are present in the list or with a single condition if not.

Comment: So `deviceTypes` contains only those two strings `"typeA"` and `"typeB"` or additional things we have to care to ignore?

Comment: It could contain also other things we should ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may store the association between the `deviceTypes` strings and the predicate expressions in a map like

```java
final Map<String,String> typeToExpression
    = Map.of("typeA", "type like 'A%'", "typeB", "type like 'B%'");
```

<sup>Or use `static final`. This factory method requires Java 9+ but constructing a map should be straight-forward.</sup>

Then, one solution would be

```java
String query = "select device, manufacturer, type from devices where username = ?";
query += deviceTypes.stream()
    .map(typeToExpression::get).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .reduce((a, b) -> a + " OR " + b)
    .map(" AND "::concat).orElse("");
```

which produces a string similar to your approach. But considering the operator precedence, I suppose, you might rather want

```java
String query = "select device, manufacturer, type from devices where username = ?";
query += deviceTypes.stream()
    .map(typeToExpression::get).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .reduce((a, b) -> "(" + a + " OR " + b + ")")
    .map(" AND "::concat).orElse("");
```

This is optimized for your described case of having a rather small number of possible conditions, especially for two or less. But we can still reduce some of the largest string concatenation steps with only slightly more code.

```java
final String baseQ = "select device, manufacturer, type from devices where username = ?";
String query = deviceTypes.stream()
    .map(typeToExpression::get).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .reduce((a, b) -> "(" + a + " OR " + b + ")")
    .map(cond -> baseQ + " AND " + cond).orElse(baseQ);
```

Here, `baseQ` is a compile-time constant, which in turn makes `baseQ + " AND "` a compile-time constant too which is combined with the predicate(s) in one step. If there is only one matching predicate, only one string concatenation will be performed. Further, if no matching predicate has been found, this evaluates to the already existing constant `baseQ` string.

But if you expect large numbers of predicates, a different approach should be used, optimized for larger numbers of elements, at the expense of the small number cases:

```java
final String baseQ = "select device, manufacturer, type from devices where username = ?";
String query = deviceTypes.stream()
    .map(typeToExpression::get).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(
        () -> new StringJoiner(" OR ", baseQ + " AND (", ")").setEmptyValue(baseQ),
        StringJoiner::add,
        StringJoiner::merge)
    .toString();
```

Unlike the other approaches this will always put brackets around the predicates, even if there is one, but it will still only use that single pair of brackets when there are three or more. It avoids performing multiple string concatenations in a row by letting the `StringJoiner` do the entire work.